# Is there a max ratio that you need to stay under when you notch a newel post in order to secure it to the joists?

Tags: stairs, post

I am talking about this situation
[image]

Here is my situation:

[image]

I have two posts that I am dry fitting right now and one of them will be sandwiched between a structural joist and the stringers for the stairs that go to the basement. This will be screwed to the joist and to the stringer. from the side of the joist opposite to the viewer. I have access there, under that there is a crawl space.
The other one (on the left int he picture) will rest on the joist on a 1" shoulder and it will probably be screwed to it from the side. I have like 1" of drywall there which I can cut through and then notch the post to be flush with the wall OR if 1" thickness is not enough it will have to protrude out of the wall like in the above picture

Here is a closer look at the sandwich, there will be no void spaces there there is a 1" trim piece of white oak that will support the glass panels and the posts will rest on it
[image]

Comment: I would use the minimum.  It is side forces, so the more that is cut, the less the post can withstand.

Comment: that is common sense logic but there must be some code prescriptions here.

Comment: I think it depends on the wood/material used.  Some wood splits easy, some is a female dog to split, at least with an axe.  The force downwards can probably be held by the bolts/anchors, so a step/cut is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code only dictates the side load minimums (200 lbs) on handrail systems, not one part. I think the only time the code dictates anything about newels is the placement and the exceptions, not how they are notched or fastened.

IMO, a 1" tenon cut in the way you picture will not hold over time. If the newel is oak, you may have a better chance, but if it is a weaker wood, then 1" is too small. If the 1" tenon was turned 90 degrees the 1" portion would be reinforced by the handrail or even the post at the stairs. My minimum dimension for newels lapping over a joist is no less than 1 1/2". The smaller the newel. the bigger it needs to be. If there is another handrail coming from a different direction to aid in support then in some cases the newel can simply set on the floor, as in a corner situation where a newel is braced by a wall on one side and a strong set newel in the other direction. In some cases the joist or whatever is finishing out the framing of the stairwell and is carryng no more than the end of the plywood subfloor, I will not hesitate to cut into that member if it is resting on a wall below.

The newel to the left where it engages the stair carriage, gives a lot of good fastening there. Depending on its construction, it can be cut into as well, with discretion.

I have on many occasion cut out the drywall to get that extra 1/2" in a thicker lap piece. To save a drywall repair I cut the drywall 1/4" inside the line the newel covers, and I cut the relief in the newel 1/2" deep by 3/8" in to give 1/8" play room. This will still let the drywall look like it disappears behind the newel. Sometimes because of drywall mud or framing differences, the relief cut needs to be more than 1/2" deep.

Comment: Yeah I might have to cut into the end of the joist -you can see in the update to the OP what the framing looks like. I do not think that I want to cut the stringer as that supports the stairs :-))  The wood is indeed white oak. What screws would you recommend for this ?

Comment: White oak is a big plus, its better that red oak for strength. About the screws, it depends on the application. If it is hidden the Simpson brand  or equivalent to ledgerlok or something with a large flat head, like a washer head screw. If it is to be in the finished face a drywall screw or something similar in a counter bored hole 1/2" in diameter, filled with a plug cut from a scrap of the post, from the same side the plugs go on so the grain has the best chance of blending in. In all cases all newels are bedded in polyurethane based construction adhesive

Comment: Since the side section I will be putting the screws in will be aroud 2.75"x6" (the support beam is a 2x6 or 2x8) what size should the screws be ?  Should I predrill the holes ? These screws are pretty big (section wise)

Comment: Going through white oak into framing, predrill the oak just shy of the screw diameter so it is a very snug fit. The predrill for the framing can be, for the most part smaller than the  shanks the threads are on. Some screws do not need predrilling into softer woods. Oak needs predrilling in any case. I use construction adhesive as my main bond. The screws draw the posts in place and hold it there until the glue dries.  I keep 4, 5 and 6" screws on hand for newels. All fit in a 1/2" dia. counter bore if needed. I get at least 1"+ into the joining wood. Anything over 1 1/2" is overkill.

Comment: Is it an option to use an auger bit, drill both the floor and the newel post and then glue metal pipe in that hole and then the post to the pipe with ...epoxy?
Someone inspired me by asking if I could use an 1" dowel there but I already had that and it id not feel great. It always felt shaky

Comment: I have done that one time a long time ago. It is difficult getting a hole drilled plumb into the framing, and a well centered hole in post, that remains well centered through its' depth. When I assembled it, I had to spin it so the out of level direction was facing the guardrail, and the cut length of the guardrail pushed it out into plumb. If either hole is drilled out of plane in 2 directions, it may not still end up being plumb. Another thing, end grain does not like being drilled, especially oak. I don't want to sound wishy washy, but since it is a white oak newel, having a  (Cont.)

Comment: 1"X2 3/4" tenon is a lot stronger than even a douglas fir tenon the same size. You get that glued and screwed in place between those framing members, the strength will be most foreboding I am sure. But it must be glued the full lenght of the tenon and the cheek cuts too to minimize the tendency to rock at all. Don't test it until the glue has set up fully for a few days if possible. I know it will be hard to do, but any movement may create a void that will show as weakness in the strength of the newel.

Comment: I did not consider the posdible out of plumb holes, good poin thank you